# Implementing Comparable interface for a generic class with Type parameter

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

```
public class ClassX<T> implements Comparable<ClassX<T>> {

   private T o;

   public ClassX(T o) {
       this.o = o;
   }

   public T getObject() {
       return o;
   }

   public void setObject(T o) {
       this.o = o;
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(ClassX<T> arg0) {
       return o.compareTo(arg0.o);
   }
}
```

If I have a class like this and I want to implement the Comparable interface, I read that I have to change `ClassX<T>` to `ClassX<T extends Comparable<T>>`. But what if I also want to use my ClassX for objects that don't implement the Comparable interface, knowing that I would not be able to use the method compareTo() for those objects?

Comment: "what if I also want to use my ClassX for objects that don't implement the Comparable interface" - Then you will be basically in violation of the `Comparable` interface contract.

Comment: So you want something like "conditional implementation of `Comparable`"? That is, `ClassX<T>` will implement `Comparable` if and only if `T` implements `Comparable`? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Sweeper exactly!

Comment: I believe you should define your class like this:
````public class ClassX<T> implements Comparable<ClassX<T>>````

Comment: It would help if you explain what is the ultimate goal. What problem are you trying to solve? `Comparable` is needed to establish a natural order for objects of a certain type. You cannot do this when some objects are "comparable" and others are not. Perhaps you are implementing the Comparable interface for the wrong reason.

Comment: @hfontanez for example, if I create an `ArrayList<ClassX<T>>`, I want to have have the option to use `Collections.sort()` on my `ArrayList`.

Comment: EXACTLY... in order to do this, ALL objects in your collection must be Comparable. You cannot do what you asked. Basically, to sort, you must compare two objects. To compare these objects, they must be "Comparable".

Comment: @hfontanez  But I still want to have the option of creating objects from `ClassX<T>` without them implementing comparable.

Comment: Why? What is the purpose? Why collect objects in a data structure where some are comparable and others are not? Keep them separate.

Comment: I'm basicly creating a generic class that is a pair of 2 objects `Pair<L,R>`. The user may want to sort an `ArrayList` of `Pair<L,R>`. But other user may want to create pairs just to group 2 non comparable objects just to have them linked.

Comment: One (ugly) way to do this is to try to cast `T` to `Comparable`, and if it fails, throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`. Conditional implementation does not exist in Java.

Comment: @Sweeper key word there is "ugly".

Comment: "The user may want to sort an ArrayList of Pair<L,R>" - Why not then create an array list of `Object` objects? The reason why is because it is super ugly and messy. But the language supports it So, why not do it? Likewise, why create a collection of thing that are different in nature. A pair of comparable objects and a pair of non-comparable objects are not the same TYPE. So, why insist in making them the same or alike? It is a terrible thing to do in principle. As @Sweeper put it, it is an ugly implementation.

Comment: @hfontanez Well, something similar to that happens when you try to sort a `Stream` of non-`Comparable` objects. If `Stream` uses this approach, I'd say it's fine to use it in our code too, albeit ugly.

Comment: I'm not trying to compare comparable objects with non-comparable objects. I may want to sort an `ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>>`, but there may be another user that just wants to use the class Pair to store (for example) `Pair<Country, Capital>`. And `Country` and `Capital` may not implement `Comparable`. And I don't want to make myself implement the Comparable interface everytime I want to use the class Pair.

Comment: OP, now that you said you are making a `Pair` class, I suggest _not_ doing that. Write more specific classes instead. They are more future-proof, among other things.

Comment: @Hydrametr0nice Sweeper's suggestion should work. Keep in mind this is "ugly" as he puts it, but I don't recommend it. I still think you are either solving the wrong problem, or not thinking of a better way to do it (i.e. keep them separate).

Comment: @Sweeper "OP, now that you said you are making a Pair class, I suggest not doing that. Write more specific classes instead. They are more future-proof, among other things." Could you explain why? I'm intrigued.

Comment: How is this useful? You are better off having those generic classes implementing comparable or if you don't know the types use an **Comparator** .That Or  implement your own interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is, instead of implementing `Comparable`, have a static method that returns a `Comparator`, and this method can only be called when the constraint on `T` is met. So then your `ClassX` can be used with `T` that do not implement `Comparable`, but you can only obtain `Comparator`s for `ClassX`s with `T` that do implement `Comparable`.

```
public class ClassX<T> {
    private T o;

    // ...

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<ClassX<T>> getComparator() {
        return (x, y) -> x.o.compareTo(y.o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating another layer of hierarchy to support this:

```
public class NonComparableClassX<T> implements Comparable<NonComparableClassX<T>> {
 // ....

  @Override
   public int compareTo(ClassX<T> arg0) {
     // throw Exception;
   }
}

public class ClassX<T> extends NonComparableClassX<T> {
 // ....

  @Override
   public int compareTo(ClassX<T> arg0) {
     // Implement comparables here
   }
}
```

This way you can encapsulate all objects as ClassX, which can also be of the type NonComparableClassX if need be